# EditText is not showing hint as well as text when typing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

EditText is not showing hint as well as text when typing.
Here is code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password."
        android:text="Enter password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailText"
        tools:text="Enter Password"/>
```

I also tried to set color by code but it didn't worked:

> final EditText passwordText = (EditText)
>   findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
>           passwordText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
>           passwordText.setHint("Enter your Password.");
>           passwordText.setHintTextColor(Color.BLACK);

Note: I'm using android studio 2.3.3;

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: dont set hint and text together use hint only

Comment: You can also use WYSIWYG editor for XML elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using text and hint both together so hint is not visible.

Remove **'text'** tag into the **EditText** :'android:text="Enter password"' and  'tools:text="Enter Password"', if text is set then hint will not display.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailText"
/>
```

Hope it will help..

Answer (score 2):

because you are using both `text` and `hint`, delete the `text` tag change `height` to `wrap_content` too

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailText"
/>
```

Comment: where is `width` ?

Comment: what `width` ??

Answer (score 2):

Use  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
and use hint only

Answer (score 1):

Change height and try

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password."
        android:text="Enter password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailText"
        tools:text="Enter Password"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the `height` value or set it to `wrap_content`. You are setting height too small so text is not visible to you. You can use `hint` and `text` properties at the same time. There is no issue with that .